# How do I dynamically create an ul that won't have a set length?

Tags: jquery, list, dynamic, unordered

I know that I have to use the append() method, but the number of line items in the list will vary every time and I'm not sure which part of the ul should go in my html as a skeleton for the list and which part should be added dynamically with append() via my script.

```js
/* 
 * The function I want to create the list queries my database and pulls rows
 * of data that I want to put into a list. The number of rows will vary. Ignore
 * everything up until the list of variables.
 */ 
var activityInfo = function(niche, actvtyId){

  var info = Parse.Object.extend(niche); 
  var query = new Parse.Query(info);

  query.equalTo("objectId", actvtyId);

  query.first({
    success: function(results) {
      var activity = results.get("activity");
      var ageGroup = results.get("ageGroup");
      var numPPL = results.get("numPPL");
      // I'm not sure if I should put an empty ul in my html and then add the
      // line items or what?   
      $('ul').append("<li>" + activity + ' ' + ageGroup + ' '+ numPPL"</li>");
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: this seems fine.... what is the structure of `results` object

Comment: agree with Arun, the only thing I would do is assign an ID to your unordered list and use that to query so that JQuery won't screw up any other ul tags on your site